# Python: "Unbreakable" infinite loop was exited

Tags: python, bluetooth, hci

I'm recording data with a RuuviTag Bluetooth sensor which sends temperature values to my RaspberryPi.

According to the RuuviTag Python library docu I'm supposed to use the function `RuuviTagSensor.get_datas(handle_data)` which starts an infinite loop of the function `handle_data()`.
In my case, I designed it like:

```
def handle_data(found_data):
    temperature_measurement = found_data[1]['temperature']
    publish_via_mqtt(temperature_measurement)
```

and I wrapped it all up in:

```
while True:
    try:
        RuuviTagSensor.get_datas(handle_data)
    except Exception:
        logger.exception(f"An error occurred at {datetime.now(timezone.utc)}")
        reconnect_mqtt()
```

However, overnight, I broke ...

The logs say:

```
INFO:ruuvitag_sensor.ble_communication:Problem with hciconfig reset. Retry reset.
INFO:ruuvitag_sensor.ble_communication:Problem with hciconfig reset. Retry reset.
INFO:ruuvitag_sensor.ble_communication:Problem with hciconfig reset. Retry reset.
INFO:ruuvitag_sensor.ble_communication:Problem with hciconfig reset. Exit.
```

So it seems like the RaspberryPi hat a Bluetooth problem and tried to reconnect with the Ruuvis ... and when that did not work 3 times, he just **EXITED PYTHON**? Am I correct? Is there a way to restart the whole script if it is exited or handle this exit?

Comment: The log entries were not written by me, they are from the ruuvitag library. My logger message "logger.exception(f"An error occurred at {datetime.now(timezone.utc)}")" did not get written, but the loop was exited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the library [code](https://github.com/ttu/ruuvitag-sensor/blob/9992e5b5fd82e3a749f926214ef675e836f06172/ruuvitag_sensor/ble_communication.py#L76), `exit(1)` is called if the  sensor cannot be started after three attempts.

Calling [exit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=exit#exit) raises the SystemExit exception.  [SystemExit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#SystemExit) does not inherit from `Exception`, and so is not caught by the try/except block in the code in the question.  This behaviour seems to be intentional, according to the project's README:

> In case of errors, application tries to exit immediately, so it can be automatically restarted.

Trapping `SystemExit` within the program is possible (`except SystemExit:`) if you want to force the library to keep retrying.